# How to use reflection on zipped content without extracting

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, zip

I am able to retrieve list of file inside a zip file by using :

```
 var files = ZipFile.Open(_buildPath, ZipArchiveMode.Read).
             Entries.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

But Need to get the version info of file(s):

```
var randomEntry= ZipFile.Open(_buildPath, ZipArchiveMode.Read).
     Entries.Where(x => x.Name == "Random.EXE").FirstOrDefault(); 
     FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(randomEntry);
```

Is there a way I can use reflection on a zip file content.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the file into a temp file, get the version information and delete it.  I think that is the best you will be able to do.  The native Win32 API's for reading version information also require a path and not just a stream.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003(v=vs.85).aspx